# Unknown CMake command "catkin_run_tests_target"

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i am currently working to get packages working and activating the workspace in catkin

When i start a new Terminal i get this:

```
bash: ~catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

in english that would be no files or directory found

Using the command "catkin_init_workspace" gives me the response:

```
File "/home/creesy/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" already exists
```

when I got for cd .. to get to the upper directory and use "catkin_make" I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/roslint/cmake/roslint-extras.cmake:67 (catkin_run_tests_target):
  
Unknown CMake command "catkin_run_tests_target".

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  operator_ws/src/taurobtrackerapi/taurob_teleop_twist_joy/CMakeLists.txt:35 (roslint_add_test)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/creesy/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/creesy/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:1356: die Regel für Ziel „cmake_check_build_system“ scheiterte
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Fehler 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Edit1:

My developement environment paths looks like following

`~/catkin_ws/src/operator_ws` and `~/catkin_ws/src/realsense-2.0.3`

I also have I think the normal installfiles of ROS under `/opt/ros/kinetic/..`

I think that means i have 2 different workspaces in catkin named `operator_ws` and `realsense-2.0.3`

Edit2:

After experimenting now further and getting the `operator_ws` folder out of catkin workspace i can at least build the realsense folder. That could mean that in the first folder there are undefined dependencies or errors. I cant really understand that since it works for collegues of me

Edit3:

I just figured why it works for my collegues. they are not using the realsense camera and only the `operator_ws` which means they don have the problems with nested things.
does that mean i have to get both the `operator_ws`folder and the `realsense` folder in one upper folder for a single workspace?

Edit4:

I am trying to build only the `operator_ws` workspace and leaving out the realsense camera related packages getting the error i have problems with all together.

> ```
> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosserial_server'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(operator_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_server)
> -- Boost version: 1.58.0
> -- Found the following Boost libraries:
> --   system
> --   thread
> --   chrono
> --   date_time
> --   atomic
> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'taurob_teleop_twist_joy'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(operator_ws/src/taurobtrackerapi/taurob_teleop_twist_joy)
> CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/roslint/cmake/roslint-extras.cmake:67
> (catkin_run_tests_target):
>   Unknown CMake command "catkin_run_tests_target".
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   operator_ws/src/taurobtrackerapi/taurob_teleop_twist_joy/CMakeLists.txt:35
> (roslint_add_test)
>
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "/home/creesy/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also "/home/creesy/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> Invoking "cmake" failed
> ```

I have the feeling that there must be a fault in the files themself which cancels the invoking of `cmake` could that be right or is it still about the nesting issue? It just looks for me like there are problems with `taurobtrackerapi` and if that is the case i have to ask my collegues what they have done different

Edit5:

Here is a picture of the workspace `operator_ws` collegues said i just have to download it and it works. Maybe that isnt the whole story about it?

[image: image description]

Edit6:

Ok i think i am just too stupid, i should just get the files out of the src in `operator_ws` or instead of catkin directory use catkin_make in the `operator_ws` folder

Edit7:

I have done everything you stated in your last reply

`operator_ws` is no more in `~/catkin_ws/src` there is only realsense as workspace left now.

I think my problem with `operator_ws` is that it has several directories and it looks like the `catkin_ws` directory

`build`       `gcount.csv`  `mapping.bash`  `rviz.bash`    `Start_ALL.bash`
`counts.txt`  `_gcounter`   `math`          `serial,time`  `Start_ALL (Kopie).bash`
`devel`       `logs`        `rospy`         `src`          `watchdog.bash`

Edit8:

Copying all files from `operator_ws/src` to `catkin_ws/src` worked so far with all but one package container.

somehow `navigation-kinetic-devel` doesnt want to be build since one file doesnt grant me Permissions. I will ask my collegues tomorrow on how to solve this.

Still many thanks for all the work and advice

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291041/unknown-cmake-command-%22catkin_run_tests_target%22/) by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:\

> ```
> ~catkin_ws/
> ```

Could you please post the line from your `.bashrc` where the workspace is sourced? It is at least missing a slash (`/`) between `~` and `catkin_ws`, but perhaps also either a dot (`.`) or `source`.

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-14**:
i managed to get rid of the first problem i had by opening a new terminal with `gedit ~/.bashrc &` and then outcommenting the last lines in there. you mean: `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` ?
i still have the problem that somehow the CMake command is unknown

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:
The line you commented is probably something you'd want there. Unless you want to source your workspace manually in each new terminal.

re: other problem(s): at this point I'd recommend to `rm -rf $HOME/catkin_ws/build $HOME/catkin_ws/devel` and redo all steps.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:
Don't forget `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` before you start using `catkin_make` or any of the other commands.

Also: what is the `operator_ws` path that appears in the error message? Do you have multiple workspaces?

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-14**:
`operator_ws` path are multiple ros packages for the robot we are using. it could be that i have multiple workspaces since everything got a bit messy there. about the sources in .bashrc i have multiple lines with the same sources i just outcommented the ones making problems.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:
I recommend you read up on [Catkin workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces), particularly how things work with multiple workspaces and when you should/shouldn't source others. I suspect all of your workspaces are now chained, which is probably not a desirable situation.

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-14**:
yeah if it prevents me from using the different packages for the robot then definately not desired. im currently trying to rebuild catkin

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-14**:
OK I used your suggestions about removing build and devel. now when i try to redo the steps for making the directories I get the error that `invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed` because there are denied permissions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:\

> Im currently trying to rebuild catkin

Are you referring to the `catkin` package itself here? That would seem to be unnecessary.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:
re: permission errors: I believe it would be good if you could describe your development environment a bit better/more. Please detail all workspaces you have (ie: paths), how they relate and how you normally build and source them.

Very concretely however: have you ever run things with `sudo`?

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-14**:
ok i will try my best here. So i do have `catkin_ws/src/operator_ws` and `catkin_ws/src/realsense2.0.3` I think those are 2 different workspaces? i do also have ROS related stuff under `/opt/ros/kinetic/...` which i think is the default place for the downloaded ros files. I use catkin_make to build

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-14**:
I tried following the instructions during the installing of the packages but to be honest i have mostly no real clue what i am really doing there trying my best getting used to it with tutorials and such but it seems i havent sourced correctly or something is missing. And yes i tried sudo too

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:
Please just edit your original question text. Use the `edit` button/link for that. Append the new info to the end and prefix it with `EditN` (where `N` is the nr of edits you've already made).

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-14**:
should I maybe deinstall all ROS related files and reinstall everything? could that be a thing that i installed too much so files are conflicting?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-14**:
Please don't post screenshots of things that are essentially text. To show us directory listings, just run `ls -al` or `tree -L 1` or something similar and copy-paste the output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Edit1: My developement environment paths looks like following

> `~/catkin_ws/src/operator_ws` and `~/catkin_ws/src/realsense-2.0.3`

> I also have I think the normal installfiles of ROS under `/opt/ros/kinetic/..`

> I think that means i have 2 different workspaces in catkin named `operator_ws` and `realsense-2.0.3`

yes, I agree. And they also seem to be nested. That is *not* ok.

> Edit2: After experimenting now further and getting the `operator_ws` folder out of catkin workspace i can at least build the realsense folder.

This confirms my suspicions. Workspaces cannot be nested.

> That could mean that in the first folder there are undefined dependencies or errors. I cant really understand that since it works for collegues of me

I don't know why it works for your colleagues. Perhaps they've ran `rosdep install -y --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src/operator_ws -i` and didn't nest their workspaces?

---

Edit:

> I just figured why it works for my collegues. they are not using the realsense camera and only the `operator_ws` which means they don have the problems with nested things.
> does that mean i have to get both the `operator_ws`folder and the `realsense` folder in one upper folder for a single workspace?

You can either add all packages to a single workspace, or use workspace chaining. That is explained in the Catkin pages I linked to earlier.

---

re: edit 4:

> I have the feeling that there must be a fault in the files themself which cancels the invoking of cmake could that be right or is it still about the nesting issue?

I'm confused about this:

> ```
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(operator_ws/src/taurobtrackerapi/taurob_teleop_twist_joy)
> ```

```
...
See also "/home/creesy/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

notice the last line: why is Catkin entering the `operator_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_server` directory while it is building the `/home/creesy/catkin_ws` workspace? Do you still have those workspaces nested? Or is the `operator_ws/src` directory the only directory in `operator_ws`?

---

re: edit 5: if `operator_ws` is in `$HOME/Documents`, how can it be built by Catkin when you're building `$HOME/catkin_ws`? That does not make sense to me. Have you symlinked it into your `catkin_ws`? Can you please:

1. comment *all* `source` lines in your `.bashrc`
2. start a new terminal
3. `source /opt/ros/$distro/setup.bash`
4. `rm -rf $HOME/catkin_ws/build`
5. `rm -rf $HOME/catkin_ws/devel`
6. `cd $HOME/catkin_ws`
7. `catkin_make`

If that succeeds, then we can try building the other workspace.

---

re: edit 6 & 7: yes, you were still nesting two workspaces. `operator_ws` contained its own `devel` and `build` folders. That probably won't work.

You have two options:

1. put everything that is now inside `operator_ws/src` inside `$HOME/catkin_ws/src`. Treat it as a single workspace, and build that using `catkin_make`
2. move `operator_ws` out of `catkin_ws/src`, make sure to *not* have sourced `catkin_ws/devel` and build `operator_ws` in isolation

In short: you can have as many packages as you want in a single workspace, but you **cannot have `devel`, `build` and / or `install` spaces inside another `src` space**. Please review the Catkin documentation I linked earlier.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-14**:
ok thank you very much. I will try the first solution for the beginning, but since there will be other packages from my collegues who also have to get into one place i might have to go for option too later and should learn how to do it correctly . I will review the docu again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:
Could you please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark (✓) to the left of the answer if you feel it has been answered? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if you still have this issue. I had the same issue after installing Realsense ROS driver in my catkin workspace. I figured out the recommended instructions in Realsense installation page asks you to run:

> catkin_make -DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=False -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

In that case, it will set your local build CMakeCache with that variable as:

> catkin_ws$ grep -irInH 'CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING' .
> ./build/CMakeCache.txt:96:CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING:BOOL=False

So,  You can solve this issue by running with tests enabled (catking_make -DCMAKE_ENABLE_TESTING=True) and building the Realsense in an isolated work area.

---

Originally posted by [vinaykumarhs2020](https://answers.ros.org/users/21620/vinaykumarhs2020/) with karma: 126 on 2018-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-21**:
the part with building all the files seems to have worked now. currently my biggest problem is: how do i get the camera working how i want it to work and to get 3d mapping rolling since i only find tutorials for realsense r200 and zr300 who doesnt seem to work with d435

**Comment by [vinaykumarhs2020](https://answers.ros.org/users/21620/vinaykumarhs2020/) on 2018-05-21**:
You can use `roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_rgbd.launch enable_pointcloud:=true` to start the realsense with rgbd data and use a RGBD SLAM package like: https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2

**Comment by [Creesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35123/creesy/) on 2018-05-22**:
Ahh thanks for that. im working with rtabmap but i will try the suggested slam packages. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real solution but I commented out `roslint_add_test()` in the CMakeLists.txt I was getting `Unknown CMake command "catkin_run_tests_target".` error from to get past it.  Possibly there is something wrong with my https://github.com/ros/roslint (mine is built from source)- I'll update this answer if I get further in debugging this.